# При загрузке нового apk добавляются 2 новых разрешения в Google Play Console

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play-console, android-permissions

Собственно скриншот. Перед загрузкой нового apk были обновлены Android Studio до версии 3.1 и gradle до версии 4.4 [image]

Вот разрешения в манифесте

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

мой build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "myID"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 25
        versionName "27.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "MyApp - " + defaultConfig.versionName)
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard true
        debuggable = true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

}
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

androidTestImplementation ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})



implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.0'


implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.6.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:12.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:12.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Также есть отдельная версия приложения, в ней вообще никаких разрешений в манифесте не прописано, но предупреждение так же имеет место быть. Никаких серьёзных изменений не делал, только поправил макеты и всё.
Что я пропустил и как быть с этим предупреждением?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49532448/google-play-consol-automatic-add-a-permission  еще такая же проблема у другого человека.

Comment: Зависимости добавлялись, версии менялись? Откройте манифест и переключитесь на вкладку `Merged manifest` - там должно быть видно откуда и что добавляется.

Comment: @woesss, менялись версии firebase core и ads на 12, нового ничего не добавлял.

Comment: @woesss, посмотрел merged manifest там есть 2 разрешения про которые я задал вопрос, вот что написано Merging Log: Implied from the app main manifest (this file), line 1; reason: com.google.android.gms.license has a targetSdkVersion < 4.  Теперь вопрос, откуда targetSdkVersion < 4 если  targetSdkVersion = 27? Clean Project и Rebuild делал, не помогает.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases - косячок в гуглосервисах.

Comment: @woesss фух, успокоил, а то я уже устал всё кверху дном в проекте переворачивать. Спасибо большое!